# Can't run DDL statement in an Oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I need to pull a list of distinct formatted source names for a query.  I wrote a function to do this and it returns the data I want, however, because it truncates and writes to a table it cannot be used within a query in Oracle.  So I am stumped on how to make this work within a query.  Here is the code.

```
FUNCTION GET_POD_SOURCE_FROM_APP_NO
     (I_APPL_ID_SEQ IN WRD_APPLICATIONS.APPL_ID_SEQ%TYPE,
      I_DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';')

   RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS

   CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT DISTINCT SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ,
           SRNM.SRNM_NM,
           SOUR.FORK_NM,
           DECODE(POD.UNNAMED_TRIBUTARY,
                  'N',
                  NULL,
                  'Y',
                  'UNNAMED TRIBUTARY') POD_UT,
           MRTP.DESCR POD_MINORTYPE,
           DECODE(POD.MAJOR_TYPE,
                  'S',
                  'SURFACE WATER',
                  'G',
                  'GROUNDWATER',
                  NULL,
                  NULL) POD_MAJORTYPE
      FROM WRD_SOURCES             SOUR,
           WRD_SOURCE_NAMES        SRNM,
           WRD_POINT_OF_DIVERSIONS POD,
           WRD_MINOR_TYPES         MRTP,
           WRD_VERSION_APPLICATION_XREFS VAX
     WHERE SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ = POD.SOUR_ID_SEQ
       AND SOUR.SRNM_ID_SEQ = SRNM.SRNM_ID_SEQ
       AND POD.MRTP_CD = MRTP.MRTP_CD(+)
       AND POD.WRGT_ID_SEQ = VAX.WRGT_ID_SEQ
       AND POD.VERS_ID_SEQ = VAX.VERS_ID_SEQ
       AND VAX.APPL_ID_SEQ = I_APPL_ID_SEQ;


   CURSOR C2 IS
    SELECT DISTINCT TS.SOURCE_FULL
    FROM WRD.TEMP_SOURCE TS
    ORDER BY TS.SOURCE_FULL;



  C1_R    C1%ROWTYPE;
  C2_R    C2%ROWTYPE;
  ROW_CNT PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  RTN_VAL VARCHAR2(4000);
  SRC_NAME VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_SOURCE';

  FOR C1_R IN C1 LOOP

    IF C1_R.POD_UT IS NOT NULL THEN
      SRC_NAME := C1_R.POD_UT || ' OF ';
    END IF;

    SRC_NAME := SRC_NAME || C1_R.SRNM_NM;

    IF C1_R.FORK_NM IS NOT NULL THEN
      SRC_NAME := SRC_NAME ||', '|| C1_R.FORK_NM;
    END IF;

    IF C1_R.POD_MINORTYPE IS NOT NULL THEN
      SRC_NAME := C1_R.POD_MINORTYPE || ', ' || SRC_NAME;
    END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO WRD.TEMP_SOURCE VALUES (SRC_NAME)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMIT';

    SRC_NAME := '';
  END LOOP;


  FOR C2_R IN C2 LOOP
    ROW_CNT := ROW_CNT + 1;

    IF (ROW_CNT < 2) THEN
      RTN_VAL := C2_R.SOURCE_FULL;
    ELSE
      RTN_VAL := SUBSTR(RTN_VAL, 1, 3600) || I_DELIMITER || ' ' || C2_R.SOURCE_FULL;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN(TRIM(RTN_VAL));

END GET_POD_SOURCE_FROM_APP_NO;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't try to run in in a query, Call it in PL/SQL.- there are several ways to display the RTN_VAL, depending on how you're going to use this process.

Comment: Although the actual problem is your use of that TEMP_SOURCE table. Just write some plain old SQL to do this

Comment: It is used within an SSRS report that is based on a query and the application number comes from that query as it is processing.  I use a view for most of the query fields, but again the view is based on a query, a very large query with lots of selects inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure SQL version which does away with the need for temp tables and unnecessary DDL.

```
with C1_R as ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ,
           SRNM.SRNM_NM,
           SOUR.FORK_NM,
           DECODE(POD.UNNAMED_TRIBUTARY,
                  'N',
                  NULL,
                  'Y',
                  'UNNAMED TRIBUTARY') POD_UT,
           MRTP.DESCR POD_MINORTYPE,
           DECODE(POD.MAJOR_TYPE,
                  'S',
                  'SURFACE WATER',
                  'G',
                  'GROUNDWATER',
                  NULL,
                  NULL) POD_MAJORTYPE
      FROM WRD_SOURCES             SOUR,
           WRD_SOURCE_NAMES        SRNM,
           WRD_POINT_OF_DIVERSIONS POD,
           WRD_MINOR_TYPES         MRTP,
           WRD_VERSION_APPLICATION_XREFS VAX
     WHERE SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ = POD.SOUR_ID_SEQ
       AND SOUR.SRNM_ID_SEQ = SRNM.SRNM_ID_SEQ
       AND POD.MRTP_CD = MRTP.MRTP_CD(+)
       AND POD.WRGT_ID_SEQ = VAX.WRGT_ID_SEQ
       AND POD.VERS_ID_SEQ = VAX.VERS_ID_SEQ
       AND VAX.APPL_ID_SEQ = I_APPL_ID_SEQ;
 ) , fmt as (
 select  distinct  nvl2(C1_R.POD_MINORTYPE, C1_R.POD_MINORTYPE || ', ', null)
            || nvl2(C1_R.POD_UT  C1_R.POD_UT || ' OF ', null)
            || C1_R.SRNM_NM
            || nvl2(C1_R.FORK_NM IS, ', '|| C1_R.FORK_NM, null)
           as SRC_NAME;
from C1_R
)
select listagg(src_name, '|') within group (order by source_name) as rtn_val
from fmt
/
```

The one thing this doesn't do nicely is handle concatenated strings exceeding the 4000 char limit. In 12cR2 Oracle gave us ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE for the `listagg()` clause but hardly anybody is yet on 12cR2; Stew Ashton has a workaround for earlier versions. [Check it out.](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EHSJPX1P6EEQ284YAX544WPXY.html)

Answer (score 1):

If Wernfried's solution doesn't work, I just wanted to point out that you can do simple formatting like that without resorting to a temporary table. I didn't want to mess with your formatting, so I left your second loop in place, but normally I'd just use LISTAGG for that too, and not use PLSQL for this at all.

```
FUNCTION GET_POD_SOURCE_FROM_APP_NO
     (I_APPL_ID_SEQ IN WRD_APPLICATIONS.APPL_ID_SEQ%TYPE,
      I_DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';')

   RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS

   CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN POD_MINORTYPE is not null 
            THEN POD_MINORTYPE || ', ' 
            ELSE NULL END 
        || CASE WHEN POD_UT is not null 
            THEN POD_UT || ' OF ' 
            ELSE NULL END 
        || SRNM_NM
        || CASE WHEN FORK_NM is not null 
            THEN ', '|| FORK_NM
            ELSE NULL END 
        AS SOURCE_FULL
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ,
               SRNM.SRNM_NM,
               SOUR.FORK_NM,
               DECODE(POD.UNNAMED_TRIBUTARY,
                      'N',
                      NULL,
                      'Y',
                      'UNNAMED TRIBUTARY') POD_UT,
               MRTP.DESCR POD_MINORTYPE,
               DECODE(POD.MAJOR_TYPE,
                      'S',
                      'SURFACE WATER',
                      'G',
                      'GROUNDWATER',
                      NULL,
                      NULL) POD_MAJORTYPE
          FROM WRD_SOURCES             SOUR,
               WRD_SOURCE_NAMES        SRNM,
               WRD_POINT_OF_DIVERSIONS POD,
               WRD_MINOR_TYPES         MRTP,
               WRD_VERSION_APPLICATION_XREFS VAX
         WHERE SOUR.SOUR_ID_SEQ = POD.SOUR_ID_SEQ
           AND SOUR.SRNM_ID_SEQ = SRNM.SRNM_ID_SEQ
           AND POD.MRTP_CD = MRTP.MRTP_CD(+)
           AND POD.WRGT_ID_SEQ = VAX.WRGT_ID_SEQ
           AND POD.VERS_ID_SEQ = VAX.VERS_ID_SEQ
           AND VAX.APPL_ID_SEQ = I_APPL_ID_SEQ
    ) TS;

  C1_R    C1%ROWTYPE;
  ROW_CNT PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  RTN_VAL VARCHAR2(4000);
  SRC_NAME VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN

  FOR C1_R IN C1 LOOP
    ROW_CNT := ROW_CNT + 1;

    IF (ROW_CNT < 2) THEN
      RTN_VAL := C1_R.SOURCE_FULL;
    ELSE
      RTN_VAL := SUBSTR(RTN_VAL, 1, 3600) || I_DELIMITER || ' ' || C1_R.SOURCE_FULL;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN(TRIM(RTN_VAL));

END GET_POD_SOURCE_FROM_APP_NO;
/
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Sometimes we get so involved we can't see things.  I will try this right now.

Comment: You are hired.....  Very impressive.  It worked perfectly once I added the order by.

Answer (score 0):

These two command don't need to be dynamic:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO WRD.TEMP_SOURCE VALUES (SRC_NAME)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMIT';
```

Just run `INSERT INTO WRD.TEMP_SOURCE VALUES (SRC_NAME);`

I think the main problem is your `TRUNCATE ...` and `COMMIT`. Both commands ends a transaction, this is not allowed within a query. I assume table `TEMP_SOURCE` is a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` Table.

Change your `TRUNCATE` into `DELETE FROM WRD.TEMP_SOURCE;` and remove the `COMMIT`. I am not sure but then it should work (I did not test it).

Comment: You can't do any DML in a function called from a query, so the static delete and insert will still be a problem, won't they?

Comment: As I said, most likely I mistake it. I am used to work often with RefCursors, there it works fine.